# Youtube thumbnail 404ing

Tags: youtube, http-status-code-404, thumbnails

I recently uploaded the following video to youtube.  http://youtu.be/5f3-N0kEz6E

I was initially able to choose a thumbnail from the dashboard. However, now when i go back to the dashboard none of the images are showing up, and i can see the following 404's in the developer console, see image link below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgxaP.png]

This is affecting the share image when i post on facebook. See the developer debugger link here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2F5f3-N0kEz6E

Why is this happening, and how can i now replace the thumbnail without having to reupload the whole video again? Will this resolve itself?

Comment: this appears to be resolved by simply waiting until youtube had corrected the issue.